# Stackoverflow error in scala code

Tags: scala

In this code I am trying to take union of two trees as follows:

```
class NonEmpty(elem: Tweet, left: TweetSet, right: TweetSet) extends TweetSet {

    def union(that: TweetSet): TweetSet =
    {
      def unionRec(set:TweetSet,acc:TweetSet): TweetSet =
      {
        if (set.isEmpty)
          return acc
        else
          return unionRec(right,unionRec(left,acc.incl(elem)))
      }
      unionRec(this,that)
    }

    def isEmpty: Boolean = false

    def incl(x: Tweet): TweetSet = {
      if (x.text < elem.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left.incl(x), right)
      else if (elem.text < x.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right.incl(x))
      else this
    }

}

class Empty extends TweetSet {
  def isEmpty: Boolean = true
}
```

But when I try to execute the union method, I am getting stackOverflow error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.compare(StringLike.scala:74)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.compare(StringOps.scala:30)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.compare(StringOps.scala:30)
    at scala.math.Ordered$class.$less(Ordered.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.$less(StringOps.scala:30)
    at objsets.NonEmpty.incl(TweetSet.scala:235)
    at objsets.NonEmpty.incl(TweetSet.scala:236)
    at objsets.NonEmpty.incl(TweetSet.scala:235)
    at objsets.NonEmpty.incl(TweetSet.scala:236)
    at objsets.NonEmpty.incl(TweetSet.scala:235)
    at objsets.NonEmpty.incl(TweetSet.scala:235)
    at objsets.NonEmpty.incl(TweetSet.scala:236)
    at objsets.NonEmpty.incl(TweetSet.scala:236)
    at objsets.NonEmpty.incl(TweetSet.scala:235)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Could you please add inc method definition into the post as well?? and TweetSet

Comment: added the code...

Comment: Do you understand recursive nature of inc method? this is a key to this problem.

Comment: If you have access to coursera matherials. try read relevant thread.

Comment: Consider this line: `if (x.text < elem.text) new NonEmpty(elem, left.incl(x), right)`. When `left` is empty, what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the recursion to eventually terminate,  you need to make sure the tree in the first argument of unionRec sooner or later is empty.
Since you always call it with left and right, your recursion never terminates.

Comment: but if I am recursively taking the left of the tree, should it not eventually become empty and terminate?

Comment: Left does not loose elements from being used as an argument to unionRec.

Answer (score -2):

You have `unionRec` method witch is recursive. Apparently it's invoking itself too many times which is actually lead to stack overflow.

To fix it, you should re-write it to make tail-recursive. Scala represents those kind of recursion as a simple loop.

Annotate your method with `@tailrec` annotation to make sure it satisfy tail recursive requirements.